# Apps Script Google Sheet Eliminar filas

Tags: google-hoja-de-cálculo

Estoy intentando realizar un script para Google Sheets que me elimine las filas que sean anteriores a una fecha en su columna A. Tengo el siguiente código que me lo elimina (Aunque muy lento) pero también me estropea la primera linea (Cabecera) poniendomela al final de la hoja. He intentado poner la linea 1 como bloqueada, y inmovilizarla (Que es como me gustaría que estuviera) pero no hay manera
Me gustaría que me ayudarais para ver si puedo hacerlo de otra manera que funcione más rápido, y sobre todo que la cabecera continúe estando en la fila 1 (Al ser posible inmovilizada)

El código es el siguiente:

​

> function eliminarYOrdenarEnTodasLasHojas() {
>
> var hoy = new Date(); // Obtiene la fecha actual
>
> //var fechaEspecifica = '12/28/2023';
> //var partesFecha = fechaEspecifica.split('/');   //var hoy = new Date(partesFecha[2], partesFecha[1] - 1, partesFecha[0]);
>
> var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();   var
> sheets = spreadsheet.getSheets();
> for (var i = 0; i < sheets.length; i++) {
> var hoja = sheets[i];
> var datos = hoja.getDataRange().getValues();
>
> ```
> for (var j = datos.length - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
>   var fechaCelda = datos[j][0];
>  
>   // Verifica si la fecha de la celda es anterior a la fecha actual
>   if (fechaCelda < hoy) {
>     hoja.deleteRow(j + 1); 
>   }
> }
>
> // Ordena los datos por la columna A de manera ascendente
> hoja.getDataRange().sort({column: 1, ascending: true});   } }
> ```

Gracias